# Can Node.js LTS version support global packages downloaded using latest current version?

Tags: node.js, node-modules

I installed several node.js global packages using v14.2.0 current version. Recently, I downgraded to LTS 12.6.3 version. The global packages installed using v14.2.0 current version remains there.

Can Node.js LTS version support global packages downloaded using current version? Do I have to uninstall and reinstall the global packages? Any side effect if I don't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed global packages by`node/npm`. Suppose you have installed `bodyparser`  package by node`(v14.2.0)`. Later you downgrades to version `(12.6.3)`. If any code of `bodyparser` depends on `LTS 12.6.3` then it will not compile. Otherwise it is ok  . Any module of your current package `(when you installed)` depends on  `v14.2.0` then it will surely cause problem. For more information you can read `docs` of the package you have installed.